# VATIC Annotation Tool installation - "turkic setup --database" - unknown action setup

Tags: python, linux, video, annotations, computer-vision

I'm trying to install [VATIC Video Annotation Tool](http://web.mit.edu/vondrick/vatic/)  on Linux. I followed the instructions in [README](https://raw.github.com/cvondrick/vatic/master/README) file twice, always failing to execute command:

```
$ turkic setup --database
```

which gives these two error messages:

```
No handlers could be found for logger "turkic.geolocation"
Error: Unknown action setup
```

Other turkic commands, e.g. `turkic status --verify` give the same error messages (for a given action name).

I also noticed that source file `~/vatic/public/index.html` contains links to stylesheets and scripts in turkic folder `src="/turkic/file_name"`, which can't be reached. Their true location is in `~/turkic/turkic/public`.

Any ideas what can be wrong?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should go into vatic folder when executing any commands starting with turkic.
Only inside vatic folder "actions" will be recognized.

Make sure that you issue the symbolic link command:

```
$ turkic setup --public-symlink
```

Comment: True problem lied within unsuccessful _pyvision_ installation which ended with error: `AssertionError: unexpected type long and base type tuple object for indexing`. 
Solution to this problem is to install _pip_ and then _cyvision_ with `sudo pip install cython==0.20` (found [here](https://github.com/cvondrick/vatic/issues/16)). Since `turkic setup` commands in **vatic** folder were giving even more unusual errors, I tried to run them in folder **turkic**, which gave me the error message shown in my question, hence i'm marking your answer to my question as a solution. Thx

Comment: Also worked with cython version 0.21 for me, but not with version 0.22 or 0.23.